# Error after cloning a Git in a different project NPM command

Tags: javascript, npm

I have this problem that is not letting me debug my website.

[image]

[image]

Comment: `error missing script: start` try to run `npm start` instead of `npm run start`.

Comment: or, actually, just run `npm run dev`

Comment: npn run dev is solution, thanks Matt!

Comment: Please in the future provide code and errors as [formatted markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), rather than using image links.

Comment: @MattSoltysik Feel free to post your `npm run dev` solution as an answer so that this question can be removed from the "Unanswered" tab. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have a `'start'` script defined  in your `"scripts"` section.

You could use the defined `'dev'` script (`npm run dev`) or rename it to `'start'`.

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "nodemon src/index.js"
}
```

> Tipp: Use `npm run` to list all available npm sripts